# TreeSet equals another TreeSet

Tags: java, collections, treeset

How to find out if two `TreeSet` objects are equal? I use **open-jdk-10**.

**ModifiebleObject**

```
class ModifiebleObject implements Comparable<ModifiebleObject>{

    Integer number;
    String text;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(final ModifiebleObject o) {
        return this.number - o.number;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof ModifiebleObject)) return false;
        final ModifiebleObject that = (ModifiebleObject) o;
        return Objects.equals(number, that.number) &&
                Objects.equals(text, that.text);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(number, text);
    }
}
```

**SomeCode**

```
SortedSet<ModifiebleObject> tree1 = prepare();
SortedSet<ModifiebleObject> tree2 = prepare(); //Returns cloned elements, so object references in tree1 and tree2 are different.

// ModifiebleObject implements Comparable<ModifiebleObject>
// compareTo does not use all the fields, just some of them.
//setSomeValueOutsideOfComparable sets value of the field, which is not used by compareTo
tree2.first().setSomeValueOutsideOfComparable("newValue");

boolean tree1EqualsTree2 = tree1.equals(tree2); //Returns true
```

Because

TreeSet calls `AbstractSet.containsAll` -> `TreeSet.contains` -> `TreeMap.containsKey` -> `TreeMap.getEntry != null`

`TreeMap.getEntry` uses compactor or elements compareTo (elements implement Comparable).

Funny, but JavaDoc lies!

**java.utilTreeSet**

```
/**
 * Returns {@code true} if this set contains the specified element.
 * More formally, returns {@code true} if and only if this set
 * contains an element {@code e} such that
 * {@code Objects.equals(o, e)}.
 *
 * @param o object to be checked for containment in this set
 * @return {@code true} if this set contains the specified element
 * @throws ClassCastException if the specified object cannot be compared
 *         with the elements currently in the set
 * @throws NullPointerException if the specified element is null
 *         and this set uses natural ordering, or its comparator
 *         does not permit null elements
 */
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    return m.containsKey(o);
}
```

> More formally, returns {@code true} if and only if this set contains an element {@code e} such that {@code Objects.equals(o, e)}.

But in reality it uses `compareTo`.

---

### Update

What other collection from jdk or another library I could use that guarantees unique elements and sorted, and equals to another collection uses for each element equals.

Comment: Well, if you `setSomeValueOutsideOfComparable`, the trees _are_ still equal, since all their elements are sill considered `equal`.

Comment: `prepare` returns different elements (cloned objects,  I say). So setting a field in one set, does no affect the other set.

Comment: @tobias_k I think what he means is that the JavaDoc states that `o.equals(e)` must hold true while the `TreeMap` that normally backs the set uses a comparator or `compareTo()` - and those might differ.

Comment: Yes, but if, as you say, setting that field does not affect `compareTo`, how is `tree1.equals` supposed to know that something changed? Also, the elements are probably stored in the tree by their hashcode, so doing anything that changes the hashcode may also be a problem.

Comment: @tobias_k actually, the `TreeSet()` constructor internally creates a `TreeMap` to hold the elements. That `TreeMap` then uses comparisons rather than hashcodes and equality checks to store the elements. The JavaDoc thus is misleading.

Comment: "What other collection from jdk or another library I could use that guarantees unique elements and sorted, and equals to another collection uses for each element equals." - I'd say the problem is with your definition of uniqueness and order: unique elements might have equal ordering predicates, e.g. different persons might still have the same age. Thus if you want both then you'd need to use the same fields in `compareTo()` as in `equals()`.

Answer (score 2):

The [JavaDoc for `TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) explicitly says this. It's not some conspiracy.

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit
>   comparator is provided) **must be consistent with equals** if it is to
>   correctly implement the Set interface. (See Comparable or Comparator
>   for a precise definition of consistent with equals.) This is so
>   because the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation,
>   **but a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its
>   compareTo** (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal
>   by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal. The
>   behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent
>   with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set
>   interface.

Your class has ignored [the advice of `Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) and you are paying for it.

> It is strongly recommended, but not strictly required that
>   `(x.compareTo(y)==0) == (x.equals(y))`

Comment: Two apples of the same size. comapre = 0, equals is false, because they are different objects, and different identities (for example in the purchase order database)!

Comment: Why would I want to sort my apples but not allow two apples to have the same weight? If the weights are the same, how do I determine which apple to keep and which to get rid of? I have to do it arbitrarily, but what if I discard the wrong apple? They're both the same weight, but as you said - they are not the same. Fair enough, I may want to sort my apples by weight: that's a sorted `List<Apple>`. Maybe I only care about the weights: that's a `List<Integer>`.  Maybe I want to lookup apples based on weight, that's a `Map<Integer, Set<Apple>>`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Set of Defined Object then  you can override hashcode and equals method and below method compare based on hashcode and equals method.
You can Use

```
 org.apache.commons.collections
 SetUtils.isEqualSet(set1, set2);
```

or

```
 org.apache.commons.collections
 CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection(a, b)
```

Comment: org.apache.commons.collections
 SetUtils.isEqualSet(set1, set2);

Comment: it uses Collection.containsAll. I wrote about this issue in my question.

Comment: in ModifiebleObject override hashcode and equal method and its work.

Comment: Yes, hashCode and equals ModifiebleObject are done properly and in sync.

Comment: And yes, if I tree1.equls(tree2) = true, but new HashSet(tree1).equals(tree2) = false, good pint!

Comment: +1,  org.apache.commons.collections
 CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection(a, b) - it works because it uses inner HashMap get count. HashMap uses hashcode() to find an object.

Comment: yes, I faced similar problems like you. when i get a sorted object from db which is persistsort and my incoming object is treeset and i am trying to find the intersection. which return an incorrect result and many libraries tried google and apache library etc. gives same result and after reseaching i found CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection is check hash and equal and its work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that worked for me.

```
class TreeSetWithEquals extends TreeSet {

    //Constructors which I will use
    //

    // I consider two sets equal if they have equal elements in the same order!
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        //Check if Object not null, not the same reference as this, and 
        // it is instance of Set
        //And their sizes are equal
        //Iterate through boths sets and apply equals for each method.
    }
}
```

Why would I do this? Well, in our code we generate equals for other objects in Idea -> which uses `Objects.equals(this.field_i, that.field_i)`. We are lazy to search our code for places and replace `Objects.equals(this.field_i, that.field_i)` if `field_i` is a sorted set into a util class to check equality of the sets. So it is easier to use a set which supports sorting, but uses `eqauls` for each element inside `this.equals`.

Some people tell me that `eqauls`, `hashCode`, `compareTo` must be consistent. I agree with `eqauls`, `hashCode`must be consistent.

For example.

```
enum WeaponType {

     KNIFE,
     HAND_GUN,
     TWO_HANDED_GUN,
     GRANADES, //To allow flash, smoke and fragmentation granades
     DEFUSE_KIT
}

class Shooter {

    // make sure we can have different weapons,
    // but only one of type is allowed.
    // Our tree set with such comparator will guarantee this requirement.
    private SortedSet<Weapon> weapons = buyWeapons(andUseWeaponTypeComparator);
```

To do this I will define a **WeaponComparator**

```
Comparator<Weapon> WEAPON_COMPARATOR = Compareator
       .comparing(Weapon::getType, Comparator.naturalOrder()) //enum uses its element order.
}
```

Now if you want to persist a shooter and send messages in kafka to other micro-services, you will have `equals` which checks the who *Shooter* entities.